# Oxygen sensors in trace gas environments

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors, gas

Do Oxygen lambda sensors (used in automotive applications) work in trace gas environments?

My requirements for a trace Oxygen gas sensor:

1. The sensor must be capable of working in an inert gas environment of either Nitrogen or Argon.
2. The sensor's operating temperature is not more than 40-50 degrees Celsius.
3. The sensor is capable of sensing an Oxygen gas concentration as low as 10 ppm to an Oxygen gas concentration as high as (19-25%, that is, an Oxygen concentration of regular air).

Could anybody who is working with such sensors suggest some sensor that I can use in such environments?

Comment: Why not get the data sheets for the sensors you are looking at? That will tell you the sensitivty etc...

Comment: @SolarMike I have the data sheets of electrochemical sensors that I can use for such environments. But i don't know where to start for lambda sensors. Also, whenever I looked up trace gas sensors, electrochemical sensors were always mentioned. Lambda sensors were never mentioned.

Comment: Do you think lambda sensor is the name given to the electrochemical sensor in the auto industry as that is the function it is used for?

Comment: @SolarMike According to Wikipedia, lambda sensors are electrochemical sensors. However, the construction of the sensor is significantly different from that of the trace gas sensors (like Figaro's KE25) that I have looked up. Also, the reason why I'm asking this question is the fact that automotive applications don't deal with trace gas environments.

Comment: You are concerned about what the sensor is capable of, not how it is used in a car or the package it comes in...

Comment: @SolarMike Makes sense. However, the lambda sensor is never discussed when dealing with an inert gas environment. My application's requirement is a trace Oxygen gas sensor that can work in an inert gas environment of either Nitrogen or Argon.

Comment: So you need to ask yourself what is the “lambda function” - once you know that you will understand why it is not used in an inert gas environment...

Comment: @SolarMike If I were to ignore the inert gas environment and just think about the trace gas sensing requirement, is it reasonable to think that I cannot use lambda sensors because they work in the range of a stoichiometric air fuel ratio (which is how commercially available lambda sensors are manufactured)? Also because the ratio lambda in automotive engineering is one concerning actual and optimal (stoichiometric) air fuel ratio.

Comment: So read my first comment about the sensitivity .... if the sensor is capable in the range you need - it does not matter if is also capable in the stoichiometric range...

Comment: @SolarMike So if my operating temperature is not more than 40 degrees Celsius, then I wouldn't be able to use a Lambda sensor right? Since they work only in the range of 300 degrees to 600 degrees Celsius. I apologise for not including all of my requirements in the main question itself.